# Modify the function to transform the given string into an array where each character in the array

Tags: function

Keep getting error even when I add the missing element to solution

tried adding this:

```
var strArray = str.split ('["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]');
function convertStringToArray(s) {
  var str = 'hello';
  var strArray = str.split ('["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]');
  return strArray; 
}
const exampleString = 'hello';
const stringAsArray = convertStringToArray(exampleString);
```

Comment: Please add the appropriate language tags

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'hello'; //input

function convertStringToArray(s) {
    return s.split('');
};

var array = convertStringToArray(str);
// array = ['h,'e','l','l','o']
```